# Can't able to Access Keychain After revoke distribution certificate

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, keychain

I am working in project which is already in Appstore submitted by different developer. Now I am trying to submit updated version of the app with different version and build number. I can't able to access previously stored keychain values.

Here is the steps I did

1. Revoked the old Distribution certificate created by another person and created a new one with my machine.
2. Regenerated Provisioning Profile which is used by previous developers
3. Code signed and submitted to App Store
4. Downloading old build from App Store
5. Installing the updated build from test flight
6. Now I can't able to access keychain values already stored.

Now what can I do to retrieve the old keychain value? I have also checked the team ID for Keychain group access it is same as old one. Is there any way I can retrieve the old keychain values.

Comment: keychain group which is tied your team identifier. So, basically, access to keychain after app updates depends on distribution certificate you use, not on the provisioning profile

Comment: @ShobhakarTiwari Revoking the old Distribution certificate will cause the problem. Now I am using same team ID

Comment: you should use same old certificate for this , else data will be lost

Comment: @ShobhakarTiwari Which old certificate I need to use Provisioning Profile or Distribution Certificate?

Comment: Distribution certificate which were used to create provisioning

Comment: @ShobhakarTiwari thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here is brief answer which may help you to resolve your issue :

> keychain group which is tied your team identifier. So, basically,
>   access to keychain after app updates depends on distribution
>   certificate you use, not on the provisioning profile

So if you are saying you revoke all old certificate  and the one with the new certificate ( that you created ) that access to keychain groups will be lost for this version.

Comment: You said Keychain group is tied with team identifier I am using the same team identifier

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got a solution from apple guides

> Note: In iOS, Keychain rights depend on the provisioning profile used
>   to sign your application. Be sure to consistently use the same
>   provisioning profile across different versions of your application.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html

Comment: The quoted text is now removed from the docs. Apple removed that sentence because it's not actually true! You can use different provisioning profiles as long as they contain the same important information: Team/developer ID, bundle ID, and most importantly - `keychain access group`. Check out [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60703577/access-keychain-values-stored-by-exposecurestore-from-a-flutter-app-ios/60845994#60845994) for a more in-depth description.