# Access Keychain values stored by ExpoSecureStore from a Flutter app [iOS]

Tags: ios, objective-c, flutter, react-native-ios, keychain

I have a ReactNative app (only published for iOS) which uses [ExpoSecureStore](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/securestore/) to put and read values from iOS Keychain.

I am transitioning to Flutter and I **need** to keep the users logged in, i.e. to get their auth tokens from the previously installed RN version of the app.

So, here is what I do:

1. I install the RN app from the App store,
2. Log in (the token is saved with ExpoSecureStore),
3. Install my Flutter app
4. Try to access the Keychain - nothing found!
5. Reinstall the RN app from the App store,
6. User is logged in when I open the app!

So, my Flutter installation doesn't delete the tokens, but it can't access them.

### Update 18.3.2020.

Here is what **ReactNative's** latest build looks like on AppstoreConnect:
[image: React Native entitlements on AppstoreConnect]

Here is the same info for our **Flutter** build:
[image: Flutter entitlements on AppstoreConnect]

I tried setting the keychain group in Flutter's XCode project to all kinds of values: `TEAM_ID.*`, `TEAM_ID.`, `TEAM_ID`, `*`, `TEAM_ID.com.my_real_app_id` etc.. but nothing helped
[image: Entitlements of Flutter app XCode project]

### Is there something I am missing?

============== original question continues ================

I am using the `FlutterSecureStoragePlugin` ([link to the `.m` file](https://github.com/mogol/flutter_secure_storage/blob/develop/ios/Classes/FlutterSecureStoragePlugin.m)) to access the Keychain values.

Here is the link to the `EXSecureStore.m` file - [EXSecureStore.m on GitHub](https://github.com/expo/expo/blob/master/packages/expo-secure-store/ios/EXSecureStore/EXSecureStore.m).

- The Flutter app has the same bundle ID, so that should not be the problem.
- I've changed its source code so that I use the same keychain service (`kSecAttrService`), which defaults to `"app"`.
- Also, I've copied and adapted the code for reading the Keychain values from `ExpoSecureStore.m` to `FlutterSecureStoragePlugin.m` but still no luck..

Could there be any difference in the way RN and Flutter libraries pass strings down to native iOS? I guess there must be something going on with the Keychain access that I don't know, so any help is very welcome!

Thank You for reading!

Comment: from a quick glance, it seems ESS writes the genericPW without an access group and sets kSecAttrGeneric, while FL read with group set, and not setting generic. Did you try to match that too ?

Comment: @blld thanks for commenting! Unfortunately, that didn't help. I already tried that, as I've copied the code for reading Keychain items from `ExpoSecureStore.m`. I mentioned it in the last item of the unordered list in the question. I think there must be something hidden in the storing process I'm missing..

Comment: According to Apple document, I think you should use `Keychain Sharing capability in Xcode`. [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/keychain_services/keychain_items/sharing_access_to_keychain_items_among_a_collection_of_apps) you can find more information about it.

Comment: @RezaDehnavi that's exactly what I did when I added `Keychain access groups`. Having at least one value in that array inside the entitlements file automatically enables it.

Comment: Have you used common string as the Keychain access group in both apps? And one more thing Have you ever tried to access the RN keychain app through a native app?

Comment: Yes, I've tried setting the `keychain access group` to many values, one of which is `TEAM_ID.*` which is exactly the same value of React Native's app, as showed in one of the screenshots. Also, I've tried reading the keychain, but still no results. I finally solved the issue and I am writing a detailed answer below. Thank You for Your time and participation!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have finally solved the expo secure store access issue!

#### TL;DR

The most important things are that you set up the same `keychain access group`, same `kSecAttrService` (keychain service) and, of course, the key of the item you want to access.

Here is what are the preconditions:

- you must set the `keychain access group` to the same value as in the react native's build, which is **`TEAM_ID.*`**. This can be achieved by one of the two options:

  - setting the *Keychain Sharing* capability to **`*`**, as shown on the screenshot below, **or**
  - open the *entitlements* file (`project_dir/ios/Runner/Runner.entitlements`) and add the item `$(AppIdentifierPrefix)*` **or** item `TEAM_ID.*` to the `keychain access groups` array. Notice that if You are adding the first item, there is no `.` before the `*`, since `AppIdentifierPrefix` is converted into `TEAM_ID.` before the build. [Link to the apple docs on the `keychain-access-groups` entitlement](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2415/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40016427-CH1-ENTITLEMENTSLIST).
    [image: xCode keychain access group setup for react native / expo and flutter]
- If the app you are developing has **the same bundle ID** (i.e. it's an update to the existing ReactNatvie/Expo app), you should not have any problems with accessing the keychain items (when you do all the other preconditions, of course). **Also, if the app has the same keychain sharing group**, in this case `TEAM_ID.*`, it should also be able to access the keychain items. Notice that having the keychain access group set to TEAM_ID.* means that only apps developed by same developer (team) can access the RN app's keychain items.
- you must change the Flutter's library (or the native iOS) source code so that it **uses the same keychain service (`kSecAttrService`) as Expo**. For Expo, if You don't pass the `keychainService` param in the SecureStore options, the `kSecAttrService` attribute of the item you want to write (or get) will be **`app`**. You can see that yourself [**here**, on the expo native library's source code on GitHub (link)](https://github.com/expo/expo/blob/master/packages/expo-secure-store/ios/EXSecureStore/EXSecureStore.m#L14). I made a fork of the flutter library and I will make a pull request sometime in the future, but you can just change plugin's default keychain service to **`app`** as well. It currently defaults to `flutter_secure_storage_service`, as seen in [the plugin's source code on GitHub (link)](https://github.com/mogol/flutter_secure_storage/blob/develop/ios/Classes/FlutterSecureStoragePlugin.m#L3).
- the trickiest part - because of which I doubted in all of the above steps - is **setting the correct key (`kSecAttrAccount`) for the keychain item** I wanted to get. What helped me was to use the Flutter plugin's `readAll` method ([link to the native source code of `readAll` on GitHub](https://github.com/mogol/flutter_secure_storage/blob/develop/ios/Classes/FlutterSecureStoragePlugin.m#L149)). It showed me that the keychain items were actually there, but that the keys were different than the ones ReactNative app was using. As I've found out by debugging (it's nowhere in the docs!!!), **the expo username and expo project's name are added **before** the string used for the key**! So, if in the ReactNative app you save a token with key `accessToken`, it will be saved to the Keychain as **`@expousername/project-name-accessToken`**! It's nowhere in the docs, and I don't know how it happens, because I've looked through the source code

In my question, I said that I've copied the Objective-C code from expo's library to Flutter's plugin, but that wasn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

This is the top hit for Keychain Sharing and Flutter so I just thought people should know to go into Xcode, go into the iOS folder and open the Runner.xcodeproj and then add the Keychain sharing according to the Apple docs.
https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev88ff319e7

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34750435)